How to convert to the Cartesian coordinates from new spherical coordinates after the rotation of spherical coordinate axes?
In a spherical coordinate system, an arbitrary point on the unit sphere is represented by the coordinates $(\theta, \phi)$. Although the $\theta$ and $\phi$ values are defined with respect to the $x$-, $y$- and $z$-axes in a Cartesian coordinate system, now I want to re-define the $z$-axis into the direction towards a particular direction $(\theta_0, \phi_0)$. In such a new spherical coordinate system, how the direction $(\theta', \phi')$ can be converted into corresponding Cartesian coordinate $(x, y, z)$?
I think the following expression is wrong:
$x = \sin(\theta' + \theta_0) \cos(\phi' + \phi_0)$
$y = \sin(\theta' + \theta_0) \sin(\phi' + \phi_0)$
$z = \cos(\theta' + \theta_0)$
Could you please share with me your wisdom?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
